# mailerclient not detected by playframework

Tags: java, email, playframework, playframework-2.0

*Note: I am new to play framework, please forgive me for any rookie mistakes.*

**Background Info:**

In my webapp, I make use of email functionality, and this is done by using the [MailerClient](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#java) provided as a sbt library.

The MailerClient is supported on [this](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#java) github page.

I am using github as my git repository, as this is a team project.

I initally created the project and pushed to the repository, *here is the start of the problem*.

---

**Instructions for Email Support (JAVA)** (As a reference of my steps taken)

Firstly, for enabling email support for Java, a few steps need to be taken.

**1. Add SBT MailerClient library**

Add the lines

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer-guice" % "6.0.1"
```

to the `projectRoot/build.sbt` file

**2. Configure MailerClient**

Then configure the `MailerClient` ports, etc in the `projectRoot/conf/application.conf` file

example given on the github page:

```
play.mailer {
  host = "example.com" // (mandatory)
  port = 25 // (defaults to 25)
  ssl = no // (defaults to no)
  tls = no // (defaults to no)
  tlsRequired = no // (defaults to no)
  user = null // (optional)
  password = null // (optional)
  debug = no // (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock = no // (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```

mine is at the bottom of the `application.conf` file as it doesn't form part of any other tree prefix.

**3. Proceed to the [Java Usage](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#java) tag**

**4. Inside a class (of your choice), add the code:**

```
@Inject 
MailerClient mailerClient;
```

Within this class, the `MailerClient` object is instantiated and can be used to send emails.

With the given example from the Github page, create the `email` object:

```
String cid = "1234";
    Email email = new Email()
      .setSubject("Simple email")
      .setFrom("Mister FROM <from@email.com>")
      .addTo("Miss TO <to@email.com>")
      // adds attachment
      .addAttachment("attachment.pdf", new File("/some/path/attachment.pdf"))
      // adds inline attachment from byte array
      .addAttachment("data.txt", "data".getBytes(), "text/plain", "Simple data", EmailAttachment.INLINE)
      // adds cid attachment
      .addAttachment("image.jpg", new File("/some/path/image.jpg"), cid)
      // sends text, HTML or both...
      .setBodyText("A text message")
      .setBodyHtml("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message with cid <img src=\"cid:" + cid + "\"></p></body></html>");
```

Then send the email using the `mailerClient`:

```
    mailerClient.send(email);
```

---

**Problem:**

After checking out my branch (i.e. it pulls the webapp project from github), PlayFramework didn't detect the `MailerClient`.

I can confirm that the MailerClient does *work* (was detected, instantiated, sends email, etc) as it did so before pushing to github, and no change has been made since.

To clarify, it is problem with the plugin/library not being detected.

Checking to see if it actually exists:

```
09:15:08 ✔ cybex@arch-laptop ~/.ivy2 $ find | grep mailer
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/ivy-6.0.1.xml.original
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/ivydata-6.0.1.properties
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/ivy-6.0.1.xml
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/jars
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/jars/play-mailer_2.12-6.0.1.jar
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/srcs
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer_2.12/srcs/play-mailer_2.12-6.0.1-sources.jar
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/ivy-6.0.1.xml.original
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/ivydata-6.0.1.properties
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/ivy-6.0.1.xml
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/jars
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/jars/play-mailer-guice_2.12-6.0.1.jar
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/srcs
./cache/com.typesafe.play/play-mailer-guice_2.12/srcs/play-mailer-guice_2.12-6.0.1-sources.jar
```

When initiating the sbt tool, it does resolve the `mailer plugin`

```
//...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-mailer_2.12;6.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-email;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving com.sun.mail#javax.mail;1.5.6 ...
[info] Resolving javax.activation#activation;1.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-mailer-guice_2.12;6.0.1 ...
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days back i did experienced the same problem. I solved my problem by switching to previous version of play mailer which is 5.0.

Below is the working example

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies +="com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0-M1"
```

**application.conf**

```
play.mailer {
  host="smtp.gmail.com"
  port=465
  ssl=yes
  tls=no
  user="youremail@gmail.com"
  password="password"
  debug=no
  timeout=1000
  connectiontimeout=1000
  mock=no
  // (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```

**YourController.java**

```
public class YourController extends Controller {

private final MailerClient mailer ;

    @Inject
    public EventUser(MailerClient mailer) {
        this.mailer = mailer;
    }

public Result Email()
    {
        sendMail("Donald.Trump@gmail.com");
        return ok("done");
    }


private void sendMail(String userEmail)
    {

        Email email = new Email()
                .setSubject("BLah Blah Messsage ")
                .setFrom("")
                .addTo(" <"+userEmail+">")
                // adds attachment
                .setBodyText("Please register to Event at ");
        //.setBodyHtml("<html><body><p>An <b>html</b> message with cid <img src=\"cid:" + cid + "\"></p></body></html>");
        if(mailer!=null)
            mailer.send(email);
    }

}
```

**routes**

```
GET     /mail                      controllers.YourController.Email
```